# Getting "The body you sent contains an unknown key." when trying to create a Contentful entry

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I have created a contentful model called "User" with two fields:

- id - text, unique, required
- email - text, optional

When I try to create a new entry via content management API using these parameters:

```
Headers:
X-Contentful-Content-Type : user
Content-Type : application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json

Method
PUT

URL
https://api.contentful.com/spaces/qilo7tiaixh8/environments/entries/

Body:    
    {
        "id":"whatever",
        "email": "peter@petervukovic.com"
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
    {
        "requestId": "2849bbcd7ee0486bb36b47927071f37b",
        "sys": {
            "type": "Error",
            "id": "UnknownKey"
        },
        "message": "The body you sent contains an unknown key.",
        "details": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "keys": [
                        "id",
                        "email"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong as the examples in the [official documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry/create-update-an-entry/console) aren't helpful  (they assume multi-lingual content I'm not using) and there are no debugging hints.

Answer (score 0):

Contentful DevRel here.

I just tried it and the following CURL works for me on a `user` content type that defines a `title` field.

```
curl --include \
     --request PUT \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json' \
     --header 'X-Contentful-Content-Type: user' \
     --data-binary '{
       "fields": {
         "title": {
           "en-US": "Hello Test"
         }
       }
     }' \
     https://api.contentful.com/spaces/.../environments/master/entries/\test-1
```

It looks like you were missing to include the `fields` property in your payload. About the localization part, I think it's required to provide the locale for your field values. So in my example, `en-US` is the default value and it is required.

*For using `PUT` you have to define or come up with an entry id*.

To create an entry without passing and defining an id have a look at the docs in [Entry collection](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entries-collection/create-an-entry/console/curl).

```
curl --include \
     --request POST \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json' \
     --header 'X-Contentful-Content-Type: user' \
     --data-binary '{
       "fields": {
         "title": {
           "en-US": "Hello Test 2"
         }
       }
     }' \
     https://api.contentful.com/spaces/.../environments/master/entries/
```

Comment: I tried your example and unfortunately, I'm getting the same error:   "The body you sent contains an unknown key."  The key that is unknown this time is "en-US".   I'm using Postman.

Comment: Hmm... What's your default locale then? This is copied and pasted from my terminal in a space with a `user` content type having a `title` short text field and the default locale `en-US`.

Comment: It's `en-US`.  [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/vgucty)

Comment: Hmm... Ja I don't know. Without seeing your Postman config I can not help further I think. Do the curl commands I pasted work for you?